# Apache proxy config with variables

Tags: apache

I'm trying to configure an apache as a proxy for my elasticsearch instance (REST Service).

Till now I configured Basic Auth with LDAP.

The goal is to redirect requests for
`https://elasticsearch.example.de/kibana-int/dashboard/_search`
to
`http://127.0.0.1:9200/kibana-int-user1/dashboard/_search` where `user1` is the LDAP login name (from REMOTE_USER).

I tryed it with

```
<LocationMatch "^/kibana-int/(?<MOREINFOS>.*)$">
    ProxyPassMatch   "http://127.0.0.1:9200/kibana-int-%{REMOTE_USER}/%{ENV:MOREINFOS}"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:9200/kibana-int-%{REMOTE_USER}/%{ENV:MOREINFOS}"
</LocationMatch>
```

Is it in general possible to do this with `LocationMatch`?
Or do I have to make first some URL Rewriting and Proxy that rewritten request?

Thanks for reading and helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another while of researching I finally found a solution.

It is not possible with `ProxyPass*` but with `RewriteRule` and the `[P]` flag:

```
<Location ~ "^/kibana-int/">
       Include ldapauth.conf
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule /kibana-int/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:9200/kibana-int-%{REMOTE_USER}/$1 [P]
</Location>
```